# How can OR be used in for two different columns in php my

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so what would i have to write to have an AND with an OR command for two differnt columns

For example:
 If I mysql want to choose  a row that contains the country USA AND (the area code 561 or count West Palm Beach)

Would it look like this?

```
$num_locations =mysql_query (SELECT * FROM Address
WHERE Country='USA' AND (County='Palm Beach' OR 'area code' ='561');
```

Comment: looks good to me, except for missing " "'s. What happened when you tried?

Comment: just missing the closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

yes you right only a little syntax fix

```
$num_locations =mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM Address
WHERE Country='USA' AND (County='Palm Beach' OR 'area code' ='561')");
```

Comment: thanks! is there a limit to how many I can OR with. Like could have 1 select with 21 different OR? For example WHERE Country='USA' AND (County='Palm Beach' OR 'area code' ='561' OR longitude = 35 OR city = West Palm)"

Comment: @user2444298 no, but I would recommend you to make a unique code rather than using all those OR. For example whoever is on Palm Beach or code 561 or long 35 gets assigned an specific code ID which you use to query instead of all those OR

Comment: Yeah I should probably try that because this definitely didn't work and wasn't smart   `$match_buddy= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Matching WHERE Sex='$req_sex' AND `First Name` !='$firstname' AND `Last Name` !='$lastName' AND (Monday ='$Monday1' OR Tuesday ='$Tuesday1' OR Monday2 ='$Monday2' OR  Monday3 ='$Monday3' OR  Tuesday2 ='$Tuesday2' OR  Tuesday3 ='$Tuesday3' OR  Wednesday 1='$Wednesday1' OR Wednesday2 ='$Wednesday2' OR  Wednesday3 ='$Wednesday3' OR Thursday1='$Thursday1' OR Thursday ='$Thursday2' OR  Thursday ='$Thursday3' OR '$Friday1' OR Friday ='$Friday2' OR  Friday3 ='$Friday3')");`